# RDS freeable memory vs error rates in db

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a m3.2xlarge mysql rds box in production. It is a 8 Core and 30 GB ram.

The freeable memory approximately 4000 MBs when we got huge DB timeouts. Is there any direct correlation for the same? In other words, is having a db with freeable memory less than 4000MBs not healthy?

Questions referred with no vain
[Amazon RDS running out of freeable memory. Should I be worried?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332158/amazon-rds-running-out-of-freeable-memory-should-i-be-worried)

Below is the Freeable memory for RDS instances. We restarted the DB to increase the freeable memory
[image: Freeable memory for RDS instances, We restarted the DB to increase the freeable memory]

Comment: Memory usage is in parallel with open connections, when you open connection to rds, some memory will be reserved to that connection. Are you getting errors from RDS or your application?

Comment: From our application