# What do I need to do when AWS RDS (Mysql)'s Freeable memory is less than 20% of RDS total memory?

Tags: mysql, memory, amazon-rds

My RDS instance class is db.m3.xlarge, its total memory is 15G, I used RDS for a while, RDS Freeable Memory continues to decline, currently less than 3G.

So Freeable Memory < total memory * 20%

This Picture1 (Freeable Memory) show this:
[image]

The Picture2 (Swap Usage) show this:
[image]

According to the link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.Performance.RAM

---

Memory

Freeable Memory – How much RAM is available on the DB instance, in megabytes. The red line in the Monitoring tab metrics is marked at 75% for CPU, Memory and Storage Metrics. If instance memory consumption frequently crosses that line, then this indicates that you should check your workload or upgrade your instance.

swap Usage – How much swap space is used by the DB instance, in megabytes.

---

According to the above paragraph, should I increase the instance to increase the memory? (Modify RDS instance from db.m3.xlarge to db.m3.2xlarge)

I also found this link:

[Amazon RDS running out of freeable memory. Should I be worried?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332158/amazon-rds-running-out-of-freeable-memory-should-i-be-worried)

It said:

"Short answer - you shouldn't worry about Freeable Memory unless it is became really low (about 100-200 Mb) or significant swapping occur (see RDS SwapUsage metric)."

But My FreeableMemory is 2.9G , and swapUsage is 0 .

**Question 1:**

Do I need to expand the instance to increase memory? (Modify RDS instance from db.m3.xlarge to db.m3.2xlarge)

**Question 2：**

Will RDS's Freeable memory continue to decrease until it is less than 100M?

If this happens, what method can I use to make Freeable memory not less than a certain value?

**Question 3：**

This pictures show innodb_buffer_pool_size:
[image]

The value of innodb_buffer_pool_size is {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4} .

Is innodb_buffer_pool_size related to Freeable Memory?

I Guess:

Total memory - innodb_buffer_pool_size - database memory = Freeable Memory

Am I right?

**Question 4：**

What parameters of CLoudwatch are used to judge my RDS memory is not enough, Swap usage, Free Memory, Freeable memory?