# How to analyze Free Storage Space and Freeable Memory matrix of RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

Recently I was getting the below event in my RDS logs.

**Storage size 1500 GB is approaching the maximum storage threshold 2000 GB. Increase the maximum storage threshold.**

I Tried monitoring the cloudwatch matrices. Can anyone help me analyzing the below two matrices. What does they signify and how to read them.

[Click this link to view the matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgcdG.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332158/amazon-rds-running-out-of-freeable-memory-should-i-be-worried

Answer (score 0):

> What does they signify and how to read them

As the name suggests, FreeStorageSpace means it's your RDS's storage(hard disk).
While `Freeable memory` is your `RAM`. If this is always low, upscale your RDS or optmize your application.
You can create alarms for both in cloudwatch. You can find both metrics while making alarms in `CloudWatch->Create Alarm->Select Metric->RDS->Per-Database Metrics->FreeableMemory/FreeStorageSpace` for the respective DB.
The alarms could be `if FreeStorageSpace<20GB for 15 min` send an email or `if  FreeableMemory <= 200MB for 15min` send an email.
This is an overview, you can read more about creating alarms and setting up `SNS` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html).